# QLineEdit is causing some issues for QPushButton

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qlineedit

I created a pretty simple log in GUI and once you successfully log in, the home page will load but for some reason, all the pushbuttons get a border like this around them once clicked:

Annoying Border:

[image: Annoying Border]

Original Version:

[image: Original Version]

In order to load the home page, I basically hide all the log in widgets and create the homepage widgets.

I have created a small example using parts of my main code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

# ----------------------------------------------------

#variables

logInWidgets = []

# ----------------------------------------------------

def setLogInData(username, password, label):

    if username == password and username == "a":

        print("Yay")
        label.hide()

        for i in logInWidgets:

            i.hide()


        loadMainPage()


    else:

        label.show()

# ----------------------------------------------------

def logInWindow():

    LogInFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(window)
    LogInFrame.setGeometry(0, 0, 1000, 600)
    LogInFrame.setStyleSheet(
        "background: none;"
        "border: 0px solid;"
        "background-color: rgb(0, 20, 50);"
    )
    logInWidgets.append(LogInFrame)


    MainLIFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(LogInFrame)
    # MainLIFrame.setGeometry(250, 145, 500, 330)
    MainLIFrame.setGeometry(250, 145, 500, 335)
    MainLIFrame.setStyleSheet(
        "border: 1px solid;"
        "border-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);"
        "border-radius: 20px;"
        "background-color: rgb(255, 75, 20);"
    )
    logInWidgets.append(MainLIFrame)


    LIText = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainLIFrame)
    LIText.setGeometry(190, 1, 120, 59)
    LIText.setStyleSheet(
        "background: none;"
        "border: 0px solid;"
        "font: 16pt \'Trebuchet MS\';"
        "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
    )
    LIText.setText("Log In")
    LIText.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    logInWidgets.append(LIText)


    LIInsideFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(MainLIFrame)
    LIInsideFrame.setGeometry(30, 60, 440, 240)
    LIInsideFrame.setStyleSheet(
        "background: none;"
        "border: 1px solid;"
        "border-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);"
        "border-radius: 20px;"
    )
    logInWidgets.append(LIInsideFrame)


    UsernameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(LIInsideFrame)
    UsernameLabel.setGeometry(50, 40, 100, 40)
    UsernameLabel.setStyleSheet(
        "border: 0px solid;"
        "background: none;"
        "font: 14pt \'Trebuchet MS\';"
        "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
    )
    UsernameLabel.setText("Username")
    UsernameLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    logInWidgets.append(UsernameLabel)


    UsernameLE = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(LIInsideFrame)
    UsernameLE.setGeometry(210, 45, 180, 30)
    UsernameLE.setStyleSheet(
        "border-radius: 15px;"
        "padding-left: 6px;"
        "padding-right: 6px;"
        "font: 12pt \'Times New Roman\';"
    )
    logInWidgets.append(UsernameLE)


    PasswordLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(LIInsideFrame)
    PasswordLabel.setGeometry(50, 105, 100, 40)
    PasswordLabel.setStyleSheet(
        "border: 0px solid;"
        "background: none;"
        "font: 14pt \'Trebuchet MS\';"
        "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
    )
    PasswordLabel.setText("Password")
    PasswordLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    logInWidgets.append(PasswordLabel)


    PasswordLE = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(LIInsideFrame)
    PasswordLE.setGeometry(210, 110, 180, 30)
    PasswordLE.setStyleSheet(
        "border-radius: 15px;"
        "padding-left: 6px;"
        "padding-right: 6px;"
        "font: 12pt \'Times New Roman\';"
    )
    PasswordLE.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
    logInWidgets.append(PasswordLE)


    SignUpButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(LIInsideFrame)
    SignUpButton.setGeometry(65, 180, 100, 40)
    SignUpButton.setStyleSheet(
        "QPushButton {"
        "font: 13pt \'Trebuchet MS\';"
        "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
        "border: 0px solid;"
        "background-color: rgb(45, 227, 142);"
        "border-radius: 20px;"
        "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(128, 147, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(203, 131, 255, 255));"
        "}"
        "\n"
        "QPushButton:hover {"
        "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(128, 147, 255, 205), stop:1 rgba(203, 131, 255, 205));"
        "}"
        "\n"
        "QPushButton:pressed {"
        "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(128, 147, 255, 178), stop:1 rgba(203, 131, 255, 178));"
        "}"
    )
    SignUpButton.setText("Sign Up")
    logInWidgets.append(SignUpButton)


    ForgotPasswordButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(LIInsideFrame)
    ForgotPasswordButton.setGeometry(175, 180, 200, 40)
    ForgotPasswordButton.setStyleSheet(
        "QPushButton {"
        "font: 13pt \'Trebuchet MS\';"
        "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
        "border: 0px solid;"
        "background-color: rgb(45, 227, 142);"
        "border-radius: 20px;"
        "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(128, 147, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(203, 131, 255, 255));"
        "}"
        "\n"
        "QPushButton:hover {"
        "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(128, 147, 255, 205), stop:1 rgba(203, 131, 255, 205));"
        "}"
        "\n"
        "QPushButton:pressed {"
        "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(128, 147, 255, 178), stop:1 rgba(203, 131, 255, 178));"
        "}"
    )
    ForgotPasswordButton.setText("Forgot your password?")
    logInWidgets.append(ForgotPasswordButton)


    LIResult = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainLIFrame)
    LIResult.setGeometry(10, 300, 480, 34)
    LIResult.setStyleSheet(
        "border: 0px solid;"
        "background: none;"
        # "background-color: rgb(0, 33, 68);"
        "font: 12pt \'Times New Roman\';"
        # "font-weight: bold;"
        "color: rgb(125, 0, 0);"
    )
    LIResult.setText("The entered log in info is incorrect")
    LIResult.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    LIResult.hide()
    logInWidgets.append(LIResult)


    UsernameLE.returnPressed.connect(lambda: setLogInData(UsernameLE.text(), PasswordLE.text(), LIResult))
    PasswordLE.returnPressed.connect(lambda: setLogInData(UsernameLE.text(), PasswordLE.text(), LIResult))

# ----------------------------------------------------

def loadMainPage():

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(window)
    button.setGeometry(100, 50, 120, 60)
    button.setStyleSheet(
        "QPushButton { "
        "background-color: rgb(37, 41, 46);"
        "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
        "font: 11pt \'Times New Roman\';"
        "border: 0px solid;}"
        "QPushButton:hover { "
        "background-color: rgb(30, 33, 37);"
        "}"
        "QPushButton:pressed { "
        "background-color: rgb(18, 20, 23);"
        "}"
    )
    button.setText("Options")
    button.show()

# ----------------------------------------------------

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Border101")
window.setFixedWidth(1000)
window.setFixedHeight(600)
window.move(100, 50)

window.setStyleSheet(
    "background-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);"
)

logInWindow()

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The username and password are both 'a'. Once you type in 'a' for both and hit enter, the main page loads but if you would click on the options button, the aforementioned frame will appear.

Comment: try add  `app.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: @eyllanesc I did but it still changes the background color a little and a blue border appears around the buttons as well.

Comment: @DanielFrost I suppose you're on Windows, right? Can you provide a [mre] (including the proper stylesheet you're trying to apply)? Also, how does the QLineEdit in your title relate to this?

Comment: @musicamante I edited my question and added some code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc Any ideas? It's basically a border for when you use the tab button to switch to different buttons apparently but I can't remove it.